# Scaled version of convolution

Tags: convolution

I found that

$$
\int f(t + x) g(x) dx = f \ast g^{-} (t),
$$

where $g^{-}(x) = g(-x)$.

My question is that following integral

$$
\int f(t + \lambda x) g(x) dx, ~~~ \lambda \in (0, 1)
$$

can be expressed in terms of convolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a cool idea. The change in domain between the product convolution and sum convolution is a potential problem, if $t=0$ it might be like the Mellin convolution here: https://www.emis.de/journals/BMMSS/pdf/v25n2/v25n2p1.pdf